# MySQL-workbench dando erro de dump

Tags: mysql

Estou trabalhando com MySQL-workbench, mas quando eu vou dar um dump(importar/exportar),
Ele da um erro, olha a imagem abaixo, sabe como resolver ?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Baixe o [**utilitário do MySQL**](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/utilities/) atualizado e depois configure no *MySQL WorkBench* em `Edit - Preferences - Administrator - Path to Mysqldumptool`

Comment: Mano, eu baixei ele, mas como eu configuro o diretório, ja fiz como você mandou

Comment: Acessou o menu `Edit - Preferences - Administrator - Path to Mysqldumptool`, basta informar o local onde o `mysqldump` está instalado, por exemplo: https://postimg.cc/image/gm6g4tkf3/